# DLLimport returns gobbledygook

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, pinvoke

I have this define in C++ header file

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char* __stdcall GetId(const My_Polyhedron *obj);
```

and has this in C#

```
[DllImport("polyhedra.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]      
        static private extern string GetId(IntPtr obj);
```

It returns me gobbledygook

> îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþ2§{€ûW@_‹p

in .net 4.0, but it works well in .net 3.5.

**Note:**

1. I have tried `charset=...`(all possible settings, e.g. `Charset.Unicode`) in `DllImport`.
2. I have tried to let it returns `IntPtr` instead of `string`, then use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` convert it back to `string`.
3. I have tried `StringBuilder` instead of `string`.

All the solutions above do not work.

Comment: Have you also tried using StdCall on both sides?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  On .Net 4.0, StdCall can't work, it throws PInvokeStackUnbalance exception. I try to turn off the runtime exception, after turning off, it still returns goobledygook. On .Net 3.5, both the Cdecl and StdCall work well, returns normal string that I needed.

Comment: @william007: Do you have access to the C++ code? I suggest attaching the debugger in native mode too.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. But in any case returning string like that is surely wrong. The marshaller is going to call `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer returned. Are you sure you want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of the C++ code, you can modify the function so that it returns the string as a out parameter:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall GetId(
                  const My_Polyhedron *obj, char* result);
```

Then use this import in C#:

```
[DllImport("polyhedra.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]      
static private extern void GetId(IntPtr obj, StringBuilder result);
```

Please note that `result` is a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string`.
You have to allocate enough space first by making the StringBuilder big enough.

Call it like this:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(1000);
GetId(obj, result);
```

Use `result.ToString()` to get the string.

---

There's the `return` attribute (it isn't really a attribute) that specifies how marshal the returned value:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
```

But I didn't tried it on your code.
Maybe this helps...